# Drag and drop of TBODY elements in a TABLE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a table where I want to support dragging and dropping of tbody elements (because I have pairs of rows which need to move together):

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>...</tr></thead>

    <tbody> <tr>...</tr> <tr>...</tr> </tbody>
    <tbody> <tr>...</tr> <tr>...</tr> </tbody>
    <tbody> <tr>...</tr> <tr>...</tr> </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried various things, but am getting closest using jQuery UI sortable:

```
$('table').sortable({ items: 'tbody' });
```

And you can indeed drag and drop the rows, but:

1. When dragging the row, all the elements are bunched left.
2. There's no indication of where the tbody will be dropped. Defining a placeholder has no effect (which it does when using sortable on other elements). There seems to be no way to say that the placeholder should be a TBODY.

Any suggestions on either (a) how to achieve this with jQuery UI, or (b) another way to achieve this?

thanks,
Neil

Comment: Can you switch to a `<div>`-based layout? Really, tables are awful at being styled.

Comment: I originally started with a table, but had various issues, so switched to a <div> based layout, which I'm using at the moment. Drag and drop works nicely, but because it's basically tabular data, I'm jumping through all sorts of hoops, to create pseudo tables.